# How to calculate TCP checksum

Tags: c, linux, networking, network-programming, linux-kernel

I am writing a Kernel Module that uses Netfilter hooks to modify some of the TCP header information and obviously, before sending, I want to re-calculate  the checksum.
I also edit the header at the receiving side, so I need to re-calculate it there too.

Searching online, I found some people saying I can simply set it to 0 and it'll be calculated for me, apparently that didn't work.
I've also found this function

```
tcp_v4_send_check(struct sock *sk, struct sk_buff *skb);
```

Though no one explained how this is used, and whether I can actually use it at the receiving/sending the same way.
My own attempt was to set checksum to 0 then call this function passing the skb I have and the skb->sk I have, still nothing.

So please, what is a straightforward way to calculate the checksum of TCP datagrams?

Comment: What exactly did you set to 0 and where did you expect to find the checksum? Looking at the code, you should set tcp_hdr(skb)->check to 0, then call the function and thereafter the new checksum should be in there.

Comment: and that's exactly what I did, yet all TCP connections simply didn't work when I loaded the module.

Comment: You should probably add the `C` tag to the question. Btw, take a look at http://www.winpcap.org/pipermail/winpcap-users/2007-July/001984.html

Comment: There is a whole [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1141) about exactly this, that provides C code. Look it up.

Comment: @EJP: Thanks for the RFC :) Perhaps my question was confusing; five years ago I didn't want to roll my own, I wanted to use whatever the kernel would use (because why would I roll my own?) and had a hard time getting the function cited in the question sending correct checksums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To re-calculate the checksum, you better calculate an incremental checksum - just modify the existing checksum based on the fields you've changed, rather than reading the entire packet.

This must be done while you're changing the packet, when you know both the old values and the new values you store.

The basic idea is `tcp->check += (new_val - old_val)`.
It's a bit more complicated than this, becuase:
1. `old_val` and `new_val` need to be 16-bit values, which are aligned on 2 bytes (e.g. changing a port number).
2. The checksum uses ones complement arithmetic, so you need to do "carry feedback". This basically means, that if `tcp->check + new_val - old_val` is negative, you need to subtract 1 from the result.

Comment: This is the right way of doing it. It is faster and has less risk of data corruption. Recomputing the checksum from scratch would have run the risk of masking any corruption which had already happened to the data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example which combine netfilter API + checksum for TCP (not IP):

http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/software/tcpsp/index.html

Look into the file called tcpsp_core.c.

```
    th->check = 0;
    th->check = csum_tcpudp_magic(iph->saddr, iph->daddr,
                                  datalen, iph->protocol,
                                  csum_partial((char *)th, datalen, 0));
    skb->ip_summed = CHECKSUM_UNNECESSARY;
```

(notice it is assigned zero first, checksum calculated, then IP checksum indicated as not needed).

Depends on which netfilter module u load (there are many!!!) they will work at different layer, eg, iptable working at IP layer is shown below (image):

http://ars.sciencedirect.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S1389128608004040-gr3.jpg

Answer (score 1):

@ugoren's answer is not precise. According to RFC1624 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1624, this will sometimes produce -0 (0xFFFF), which is not allowed.

The correct way to compute checksum should be:
`new_tcp_check = ~(~old_tcp_check +  ~old_val + new_val)`

Comment: @ugoren's answer is correct, but just using your formula seem's a lot simpler.

Comment: Isn't it more simple to say `old_checksum + old_val + ~new_val`?