# How to calculate TCP/UDP checksum for non-linear skb / payload?

Tags: networking, tcp, linux-kernel, udp, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to calculate TCP/UDP headers checksum on an skb that is being sent out.

Basically, there are two functions that are supposed to do all the work 
(mentioned also in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407081/how-to-calculate-tcp-checksum) and [this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14180717/passing-packets-from-ip-layer-to-device-driver)):

- `csum_tcpudp_magic`
- `csum_partial`

For instance, for TCP:

```
  tcph->check = 0;
  tcph->check = csum_tcpudp_magic(iph->saddr,
                                  iph->daddr,
                                  tcp_packet_len,
                                  IPPROTO_TCP,
                                  csum_partial((unsigned char *)tcph,
                                               tcp_packet_len,
                                               0));
```

This works fine - I'm able to transmit TCP/UDP packets and validate checksum with wireshark on the receive side. However, I couldn't find any info regarding fragmented SKB.

**Will these two 'magic' function handle cases when TCP/UDP payload is fragmented**?

Also, it is possible that TCP/UDP headers might reside in a non-linear part of the SKB (fragmented as well).

**Will such case be handled too by these functions**?

I do understand that I can just try it with larger packets, which will cause them to be fragmented, but the price of wrong handling right now would be kernel oops, and I can't bring the system down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After lots of digging I figured this out.
`csum_tcpudp_magic` and `csum_partial` can't work with fragmented skb.
If you want to use them to calculate TCP/UDP checksums, I need to make all the packet payload to reside in the linear part of the skb.

Luckily, there's a utility function in Linux that does just that - `skb_linearize`.

So basically, the flow is:

```
  if (unlikely(skb_linearize(skb) != 0))
      ... goto drop - no memory...;

  ... do whatever you want with data ...
  tcph->check = 0;
  tcph->check = csum_tcpudp_magic(iph->saddr,
                                  iph->daddr,
                                  tcp_packet_len,
                                  IPPROTO_TCP,
                                  csum_partial((unsigned char *)tcph,
                                               tcp_packet_len,
                                               0));
```

If linearization is not possible (performance, memory, or whatever reason), then you need to calculate the checksum 'manually'.

Answer (score 0):

By the time this code runs the packet has been reassembled.

Comment: I don't see how, other than by just repeating myself. The code doesn't run until the entire packet has been reassembled, so the question of what it does with fragmented packets is moot, if not meaningless.

Comment: I don't think you understand the question: I am the one that is writing the device driver that is transmitting the packet. I get the skb, and I need to mangle with it - change some data and re-calculate the checksums.


"The packet has been reassembled" - by whom? I'm asking about TX side, so I don't know what you mean. Note that I refer to *fragmented SKB*, not fragmented *packet*.


In any case, it's been couple of hours since I asked this, and I have figured out how this stuff works.
I'll answer my own question after I get some sleep... :)

Comment: So if you're transmitting the packet it hasn't been fragmented yet.

Comment: Seriously, man... No packet. Packet - no. SKB - yes. Packet doesn't exist. SKB does. SKB has fragments. Packet is irrelevant. Packet might be short, but SKB will be fragmented.
No packet.
Only SKB (http://vger.kernel.org/~davem/skb_data.html).

Never mind...